# Flask-Babel not translating with Pluggable Views

Tags: python, flask, internationalization, python-babel, flask-babel

I am trying to get Flask-Babel to work with Pluggable Views.
Although the *@babel.localeselector* annotated function gets called as expected, translation is not actually occurring.

I have set up a demo repo of my problem on GitHub:
https://github.com/legeorges/flask-babel

We should be seeing "Hello" instead of "Bonjour" for the index page that uses a template and for the /hello page that just returns a String

There is a working sample app called [simple-babel](https://github.com/shankararul/simple-babel), however it uses Blueprint instead of Pluggable Views.

Comment: Seems we meet the same problem..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171200/flask-babel-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment48450338_30171200

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask Babel doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171200/flask-babel-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translations folder should be under app folder!!

I met the same problem..