# Flask Babel doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I use Flask Babel to do I18N for flask admin project. But cannot make it works, even with simple template. 
Here are the codes, initialize babel first,

```
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
app.config.from_object('config')
csrf=CsrfProtect(app)
bcrypt=Bcrypt(app)
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
babel=Babel(app) 
@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    return 'zh_Hans_CN'
```

Add construct admin page and add I18N, I also tries lazy_gettext()．Not work.

```
# Create admin
admin = admin.Admin(app, 'iInvest:', index_view=MyAdminIndexView(), base_template='my_master.html')  
# Add view 
admin.add_view(UserManageView(User, db.session, gettext(u'User Management')))
```

Use babel to get I18N and add translations,

```
os.system(pybabel + ' extract -F babel.cfg -k lazy_gettext -o messages.pot iInvest/')
os.system(pybabel + ' init -i messages.pot -d translations -l zh_Hans_CN')
os.unlink('messages.pot')
```

It finds all texts and add translations manually, then compile it,

```
os.system(pybabel + ' compile -f -d translations')
```

Restart server and check page, nothing get translated. I tried other languages, none of them works. What's the possible reason?
Here is the full code https://github.com/XiaokunHou/FlaskProject

Comment: If you run the pybabel commands manually, are there any error/warning messages?

Comment: @1.618 no errors, all seems well.

Comment: @1.618 it's because my translations' locations is wrong...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find where I was wrong. The translations folder is in the wrong place. It should under iInvest(which is app in other cases)..

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k lazy_gettext -o messages.pot iInvest/
pybabel init -i messages.pot -d iInvest/translations -l zh_Hans_CN
pybabel compile -f -d iInvest/translations
```

Comment: Thanks dudu, you saved my day: I'm using `zh_CN` instead of `zh_Hans_CN` in `pybabel init`, and returning `zh_CN` in the decorated `get_locale` function. The result is all `lazy_gettext` fails (i.e. the original text is displayed instead of the translated one) while all `gettext` works. Flask Babel (and/or Babel itself) is really weird...